# Why is: $\forall x(p(x)\vee q(x))\not\equiv\forall x(p(x))\vee \forall x(q(x))$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Why is: $$\forall x(p(x)\vee q(x))\not\equiv\forall x(p(x))\vee \forall x(q(x))$$
Where as: $$\forall x(p(x)\wedge q(x))\equiv\forall x(p(x))\wedge \forall x(q(x))$$

And in the same manner, why is: $$\exists x(p(x)\vee q(x))\equiv\exists x(p(x))\vee \exists x(q(x))$$

But: $$\exists x(p(x)\wedge q(x))\not\equiv\exists x(p(x))\wedge \exists x(q(x))$$

Comment: Every integer is either even or odd. On the other hand, it is not true that every integer is even or every integer is odd.

Comment: @Burak alright I see, though, this doesn't prove the two $\equiv$s.

Comment: @kuhaku To prove that the true statements are true, what are you allowed to use?

Comment: I just wanted to see how to prove such a statement. We actually didn't see a proof of this, they just showed it without proving so I guess anything that's part of 'elementary logic' can be used. (for example: truth tables, truth trees, equivalences) @GitGud

Comment: The second once, which is true, informally goes like this. Assume $\forall x(p(x)\wedge q(x))$ holds. The goal is to prove that $\forall x(p(x))\wedge \forall x(q(x))$, so let's prove $\forall x(p(x))$, the other is similar. Take an arbitrary $a$ (goal is to get $p(a)$). Since it was assumed that  $\forall x(p(x)\wedge q(x))$ holds, in particular it holds that $p(a)\land q(a)$ and therefore $p(a)$, hence $\forall xp(x)$, in the same manner $\forall xq(x)$. Hence $\forall x(p(x))\wedge \forall x(q(x))$. No room for the other direction, sorry.

Comment: @GitGud you could throw this to an answer and I'll accept it. For the other side, we'll have to take some $a,b$, get $p(a)\wedge p(b)$ and show that $a=b$? If so then how do you proceed? PS: why is this informal?

Comment: For the other direction assume the RHS is true, then take an arbitrary $a$ and try to get $p(a)\land q(a)$ by using the hypothesis conveniently. This is informal because it's not formal and being formal means that there are a specific set of rules and each step must be a consequence of some rule. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829828/fitch-style-proof/829840#829840) (in the grey section), for example, a formal proof in propositional calculus. Are you following a text book? Which? I won't answer at least for now. Maybe later.

Comment: So just assume that since both are $\forall x$ then both can be $x=a$? Ah formal proofs in this sense, we haven't seen formal proofs with predicates... I learn intro to logic, we don't have a book although I could probably get any book you could recommend.

Comment: Yes, you can take $x=a$ in both. I didn't have any book in mind, I wanted to check which one you were following to get a better understanding of what's expected of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal quantifier distributes over conjunction but not necessarily over disjunction.   The existential quantifier distributes over disjunction but not necessarily over conjunction.   This is due to the associativity of the logical connectives and their relationship to the dual quantifiers.

A universal quantified predicate is true if the predicate is true for all elements in the domain of discourse.  This is in essence a logical conjunction, and that was an old fashioned way of writing the universal quantifier.
$$\begin{align}
\langle\, \forall x \, P(x) \,\rangle\;&\equiv \;\bigwedge_x\, P(x)
\\[1ex]
\langle\,\forall x \in \Bbb N : P(x)\,\rangle\;&\equiv\; P(0)\wedge P(1)\wedge P(2)\wedge \cdots
\end{align}$$

Likewise the existential quantifier is essentially a disjunction over the domain of discourse.  It is held true if there is at least one element for which the predicate holds.
$$\begin{align}
\langle\, \exists x \, P(x) \,\rangle\;&\equiv \;\bigvee_x\, P(x)
\\[1ex]
\langle\, \exists x \in \Bbb N: P(x)\,\rangle\;&\equiv\; P(0)\vee P(1)\vee P(2)\vee \cdots
\end{align}$$

Now, then, can you see why your statements are, or are not, equivalent?  It is basically a matter of where associativity holds.

$$\begin{align}\tag{Note: $\iff$}
\because \langle \bigwedge_x \big( p(x)\wedge q(x) \big)\rangle \;&\iff\; \langle \bigwedge_x p(x) \rangle \wedge \langle \bigwedge_x q(x)  \rangle 
\\[1ex] \tag{1}
\therefore \langle \forall x \big( p(x)\wedge q(x) \big)\rangle \;&\iff\; \langle \forall x\, p(x) \rangle \wedge \langle \forall x\, q(x)  \rangle 
\\[4ex]\tag{Note: $\impliedby$}
\because \langle \bigwedge_x \big( p(x)\vee q(x) \big)\rangle \;&\impliedby \langle\bigwedge_x p(x) \rangle \vee \langle \bigwedge_x q(x) \rangle 
\\[1ex]\tag{2}
\therefore \langle \forall x \big( p(x)\vee q(x) \big)\rangle \;&\impliedby \langle\forall x\, p(x) \rangle \vee \langle \forall x\, q(x) \rangle 
\\[4ex]\tag{Note: $\iff$}
\because \langle \bigvee_x \big( p(x)\vee q(x) \big)\rangle \;&\iff\; \langle \bigvee_x p(x)\rangle \vee\langle \bigvee_x q(x) \rangle
\\[1ex] \tag{3}
\therefore \langle \exists x \big( p(x)\vee q(x)\big) \rangle \;&\iff\; \langle \exists x\, p(x)\rangle \vee\langle \exists x\, q(x) \rangle
\\[4ex]\tag{Note: $\implies$}
\because \langle \bigvee_x \big( p(x)\wedge q(x)\big) \rangle &\implies\; \langle \bigvee_x p(x) \rangle \wedge \langle \bigvee_x q(x) \rangle 
\\[1ex] \tag{4}
\therefore \langle \exists x \big(p(x)\wedge q(x) \big)\rangle &\implies\; \langle \exists x\, p(x) \rangle \wedge \langle \exists x\, q(x) \rangle 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For the first one, let $p(x)$ be $x$ is even and $q(x)$ be $x$ is odd and let $x$ be any natural number.